# YII2 export menu on kartik gridview not showing

Tags: gridview, export, yii2-advanced-app

I have installed the kartik gridview and from the [documentation](http://demos.krajee.com/grid)  and [demo](http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo), I copied some of the codes and got this one..

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'hover'=>true,
        'condensed'=>true,
        'floatHeader'=>true,
        'bordered'=>true,
        'pjax' => true,
        'toolbar'=>[
                    '{export}',
                    '{toggleData}',
                    ],
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute'=>'province',
                'label'=>'Province',
                'value'=>'cityCode.provCode.prov_name',
            ],....
```

The page displays well the gridview but the export button is missing. Do I still need to download the [export](http://demos.krajee.com/export) plugins? Or do the code lacks of important configurations??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this i hope this will Help you, Just copy and paste it, then replace fields alone with your fields thats it.

```
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

<?php $gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'companyname',
        'companyaddress:ntext',
        'hrname',
        'email:email',
        'mobile',
        'typeofcompany',
        'companytype',
        'relationoption',
        'relation',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ]; ?>

<?= ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'columnSelectorOptions'=>[
            'label' => 'Columns',
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
        ],
        'fontAwesome' => true,
        'dropdownOptions' => [
            'label' => 'Export All',
            'class' => 'btn btn-success'
        ]
    ]); ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
]); ?>
```

Comment: This worked for me, however as I understand this does not "toggle" the built-in export function of the gridview but shows a separate extension. Or is it not the case? If it isn't, then why does it look nothing like the demo on Krajee's site? The other answer below indeed turns the export options on.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the panel heading in your grid view or you should add the export button where ever you want in that grid view

```
'panel' => [
    'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> '. Html::encode($this->title).'</h3>',
    'type'=>'primary',
    'before'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>New Registration', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']),
    'showFooter'=>false
],
```